# Why can`t i post json on my razor-pages web site i made for vk bot

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, bots, razor-pages, vk

I get a 404 error when I`m trying to post JSON data on https://centroban.herokuapp.com/api/callback . It is written on c# and razor pages. Can you help me, please

This is **Callback.cs** file

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using System;
using VkNet.Abstractions;
using VkNet.Model;
using VkNet.Model.RequestParams;
using VkNet.Utils;

namespace Centroban
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class CallbackController : ControllerBase
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Конфигурация приложения
        /// </summary>
        /// private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

        private readonly IVkApi _vkApi;
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

        public CallbackController(IVkApi vkApi, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _vkApi = vkApi;
            _configuration = configuration;

        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Callback([FromBody] Updates updates)
        {
            // Проверяем, что находится в поле "type" 
            switch (updates.Type)
            {
                // Если это уведомление для подтверждения адреса
                case "confirmation":
                    // Отправляем строку для подтверждения 
                    return Ok(_configuration["Config:Confirmation"]);
                case "message_new":
                    {
                        // Десериализация
                        var msg = Message.FromJson(new VkResponse(updates.Object));

                        // Отправим в ответ полученный от пользователя текст
                        _vkApi.Messages.Send(new MessagesSendParams
                        {
                            RandomId = new DateTime().Millisecond,
                            PeerId = msg.PeerId.Value,
                            Message = msg.Text
                        });
                        break;
                    }

            }
            // Возвращаем "ok" серверу Callback API
            return Ok("ok");
        }
    }
}
```

and this is **Startup.cs**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using VkNet;
using VkNet.Abstractions;
using VkNet.Model;

namespace Centroban
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;

        }


        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddRazorPages();
            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddSingleton<IVkApi>(sp =>
            {
                var api = new VkApi();
                api.Authorize(new ApiAuthParams { AccessToken = Configuration["Config:AccessToken"] });
                return api;
            });
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

I guess there are problems with routing, but anyway, a don`t know how to deal with them.
Here is my site https://centroban.herokuapp.com

Comment: You have called `.MapRazorPages()` but not any of the `.MapControllers()` / `.MapControllerRoute()` methods. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-5.0#endpoint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly,you can try to add routing for mvc:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
```

And then you cannot use
`https://centroban.herokuapp.com/api/callback` to call the action in browser,because it is a `HttpPost` request.Here is a example to call the action in postman.

[image]

Comment: Can you accept it as an answer?Thank you.